# jQuery click event triggering when clicking wrong element

Tags: html, jquery

I made this dropzone for images as part of a another tool, and when you drop an image, it will show the filename under it in text, and truncate it if it's too long for one line.
The shortened filename is displayed as 1 string and the full filename is also written in full as another string, but hidden by default until you reveal it.

I have a "reveal" button that is supposed to hide the truncated filename and reveal the full filename with addClass and removeClass for the class .hidden --  I know I've just made some goofy mistake with my code, and clicking the .truncated span performs the removeClass, but it does not addClass...but when I click the image above, this is when the addClass bit is actually triggered, which is not what I want. I want both to happen together when I click the span with the class .truncated

https://jsfiddle.net/zos31ecu/9/ (make sure the image file name is at least 15 characters long when you drag it into the dropzone).

I know this is not the best way to achieve this, but I am still learning and it was the only thing that I could  get working properly when there are multiple instances of the same class (you can drag in more than 1 image at a time so there will be many images and captions, and obviously I just want the click event to perform that action on that one specific caption). Can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

```
$(document).click('.truncated',function(e){
    const target = $(e.originalEvent.target);
    target.next('span.truncated').addClass('hidden')
    target.next('span.full').removeClass('hidden')
   

});
```

thank you

Comment: Can you confirm that the element targeted by `click('.truncated',...)` is the same as the one you try to access with `target.next('span.truncated')`? If it is the case, `next` won't find it because it will look for following siblings, starting **after** the target element. Try with `target.addClass('hidden')`

Comment: `$(this)` not working, maybe because it's in a `<figure>` - `$(e.currentTarget)` worked, but then did some other strange things.

Answer (score 0):

Your got the problem diagnostic in the title backwards: the event is not triggered when you click the wrong element, but instead the event handler doesn't properly find the element to hide.

In the code you try to find the `next('span.truncated')` but `next` starts to search **after** the target element. In your case the `span.truncated` element is actually the target (you set the event handler on it), so you can just use `target.addClass('hidden')`:

EDIT (IMPORTANT):
The original code wasn't working properly because of a jQuery syntax difference between `.click(optionalParam, handler)` and `.on('click', optionalParam, handler)`. In the first one, when `optionalParam` is provided, it represents data that will be passed to the event, whereas for the second, if it is provided, it will be a string restriciting the selection. In this case we need to use the second syntax:

```
$(document).on('click', '.truncated', function(e){
    const target = $(e.originalEvent.target);
    target.addClass('hidden')
    target.next('span.full').removeClass('hidden')
});
```

Here is the corrected fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/p4wbkg3h/

PREVIOUS NON WORKING CODE:

```
$(document).click('.truncated',function(e){
    const target = $(e.originalEvent.target);
    target.addClass('hidden')
    target.next('span.full').removeClass('hidden')
});
```

(previous non working fiddle):

https://jsfiddle.net/38f0Lc95/

Comment: that is fantastic, thank you very much. I misunderstood the exact behavior of that. Thank you for clarifying and fixing that. I have one more question, if you don't mind assisting once more. If you click the image at any point, it removes the entire div with the image + caption. Would there be a simple way to add a caveat to this function that basically says if you click anything that is not .truncated, then it just does nothing?

edit: Apparently it applies to anything no the page if you click it, it just hides it.

Comment: @neonfontana usually we don't answer additional questions, but in this case it was me who made a mistake, you were kinda right in the title actually, because you used the syntax `.click(...)`, the query string that was meant to restrict the selection didn't work and the handler was fired for all elements in the page. You must use the syntax `.on('click', ...)`. The rest of the answer about `.next` is still valid, edited with a working code